# "В свои 41 год"

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Услышал, как Сергей Курдюков сказал в трансляции про Бьорндалена: *"в свои сорок один год".* Так правильно? Или надо говорить *"в сво**й** сорок один год"?*

Что-то подсказывает, что он правильно сказал, но хотелось бы побольше уверенности.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, есть смысл исходить из того, что, говоря о возрасте, подразумевают годы во множественном числе (в свои года, числом сорок один = **в свои сорок один год** - как упрощение). При этом не настолько важна точность (сколько ему исполнилось в этом году), чтобы с этими "годами в уме" рассогласовывать число, поэтому логично акцентировать множественное число. Но можно и обойти видимые шероховатости, заменив "свои" на менее спорное "его". А если бы речь шла о действиях в том самом году, то подошло бы порядковое числительное с обычным согласованием (в свой сорок первый год он вставил себе зубы).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!)

Answer (score 0):

Можно считать «пустографкой» этот фактически фразеологизм: посмотри в записную книжку и заполни. В этом фразеологизме слово *год* — ненужный, а значит вредный элемент.

Ответ: в свои сорок один.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/5713)

Comment: Обоснуйте! Или вы — автомат?

Comment: Спрашиваб\ют про "свой-свои" отвечаете же про избыточность слова "год". Учитывая же, что цитируют устную экспромтную речь, подобные претензии явно излишни.

Comment: В ответе указано: свои. Почему нет слова год, тому есть обоснование: ненужный, вредный, значит неправильный. Вопрос не об экспромте, а как надо говорить.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что неправильно говорить "в свои сорок один год". И говорить "в свой сорок один год" тоже неправильно. Эту фразу вообще нельзя употреблять, мы же не говорим, к примеру, "у обоих ворот" иди "двадцать двое суток", а заменяем их  другими сочетаниями: у тех и других ворот, в течение двадцати двух суток.

И здесь надо сказать что-то вроде "в свои сорок с небольшим лет".

Comment: Sergey, а вы уверены, что фразу ''в свои сорок с небольшим лет" можно понять однозначно - сорок один год, а к примеру,не сорок два или три года?

Comment: Серж, разумеется, точный возраст в этом случае не указан, но, возможно, он и не так важен. А если важен, лучше просто убрать местоимение, но только не использовать совершенно несочетаемые слова.

Comment: – Sergey, выражение достаточно распространено. Можно даже встретить  разные сочетание с этим местоимением: в свои 30 лет, 25 лет и т. д.  Мне более вероятным кажется ответ Александра.

Comment: Никто не возражает против "в свои тридцать лет", здесь мн. число местоимения нормально сочетается с числовым оборотом.  Но "в свои срок один год" - это явное нарушение грамматических связей, "в его сорок один год" тоже звучит непривычно. Если уж очень хочется сохранить фразу, лучше оставить "в свой сорок один год", здесь согласование по ед. числу дает преимущество этому варианту