# Склонение прилагательного перед числительным

Tags: орфография, согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: *за последни**й** тридцать один год* или *за последни**е** тридцать один год*?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *за последни**е** тридцать один год.* То есть *за последние годы **числом 31** / за последние годы, **а именно за 31 год**.* Смотрите мой старый [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420587/%D0%92-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-41-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4).